# My Visual Studio 2013 Express working slow

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 2013 Express.

When I'm writing in C + +, my editor is running slow, if anything I write is displayed after about 2-3 seconds.
This problem does not occur, however, in other languages ​​such as: C # / VB only in C + +.
Please help, because I have to write a group project with a friend.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

After uninstalling all **SQL** entries in under Uninstall in Control Panel, my code editor was also slow when working with C++. So I figured it had something to do with SQL and VC++ using this for IntelliSense.
After ***repairing/reinstalling*** Visual Studio 2013 Express the speed was up to normal again.

Hope this helps!